The smallest dihedral angle of convex polyhedrons
Given a set of points $\{x_{k}\}_{k=0}^{m} \subset  \mathbb{R}^n$,  is it always possible to find a constant $c=c(m,n)>0$, depending only on the dimension $n$ and the number $m$, such that, after applying a suitable rotation, translation, and reordering of the points  $\{x_{k}\}$, the following conditions hold:
$$x_0=0, ~~x_{k}^{1}>0,  ~~~ \forall k\geq 1~~ \text{  and  }~~ \frac{x_{1}^{1}}{|x_{1}|}>c.$$
Here $x_{k}^{1}$ denotes the first coordinate of $x_k$.
For $m=2$ and $m=3$, the answer is obviously ture.
the answer is clearly true. In the case
$n=2$, the answer is also true: one can choose
$x_0$  to be the vertex of the convex polygon formed by the points with the smallest angle. This is because, according to the Gram-Euler theorem, the smallest angle is at most $\frac{(m-2)\pi}{m}$. However, in three dimensions it's different, since the Gram-Euler theorem includes the sum of all solid angles and the dihedral angles.
My question is whether this holds in general for arbitrary
m and n.
A relative problem  is: for a convex polyhedron, can we find a vertex with a  dihedral angle less than $(1-c)\pi$, for some positive constant $c$ depending only on the number of vertices and the space dimensions?

For a fixed $m$, you can just project your points onto a 2-dimensional plane so that no vector between two points decreases too much. Then apply the 2-dimensional statement…

@Ilya Bogdanov, but how to project these points onto a 2-dimensional plane so that the distance between each two points  decreases not too much?

The set of all planes bad for one specific vector has a small measure…

@Ilya Bogdanov，thanks,  I may understand your idea.
